# Why is telegraf logging a 401 response from elasticsearch when using a user-authenticated SSL connection?

Tags: elasticsearch, telegraf

I am configuring the elasticsearch input for telegraf (version 1.25.0), and running into an issue where telegraf is continually logging

```
[inputs.elasticsearch] Error in plugin: elasticsearch: API responded with status-code 401, expected 200
```

The configuration for the elasticsearch input plugin looks like this:

```
# Read stats from one or more Elasticsearch servers or clusters
[[inputs.elasticsearch]]
  ## specify a list of one or more Elasticsearch servers
  # you can add username and password to your url to use basic authentication:
  # servers = ["http://user:pass@localhost:9200"]
  servers = ["https://elastic.server:9200"]

  ## Timeout for HTTP requests to the elastic search server(s)
  http_timeout = "5s"

  ## When local is true (the default), the node will read only its own stats.
  ## Set local to false when you want to read the node stats from all nodes
  ## of the cluster.
  local = false

  ## Set cluster_health to true when you want to also obtain cluster health stats
  cluster_health = true

  ## Adjust cluster_health_level when you want to also obtain detailed health stats
  ## The options are
  ##  - indices (default)
  ##  - cluster
  # cluster_health_level = "indices"

  ## Set cluster_stats to true when you want to also obtain cluster stats from the
  ## Master node.
  cluster_stats = true

  ## node_stats is a list of sub-stats that you want to have gathered. Valid options
  ## are "indices", "os", "process", "jvm", "thread_pool", "fs", "transport", "http",
  ## "breaker". Per default, all stats are gathered.
  # node_stats = ["jvm", "http"]

  ## Optional TLS Config
  tls_ca = "/etc/telegraf/ca.crt"
  tls_cert = "/etc/telegraf/clientcert.crt"
  tls_key = "/etc/telegraf/clientcert.key"
  ## Use TLS but skip chain & host verification
  # insecure_skip_verify = false

  username = "telegraf_user"
  password = "telegraf_user_password"
```

I have also attempted putting the user/password information in the url configured in the servers setting.

I have verified that I can manually connect to elasticsearch using the provider user info and certificates (via curl).

Is there a way for me to get insight into what exact calls telegraf is making so I can debug this a little bit better?

**EDIT** More info:

The curl command I am trying is:

```
curl --cacert /etc/telegraf/ca.crt --cert /etc/telegraf/clientcert.crt --key /etc/telegraf/clientcert.key https://telegraf_user:telefraf_user_password@elkdevn1.dev.oati.local:9200/_nodes/_local/name
```

To which I get a response like:

```
{"_nodes":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0},"cluster_name":"elkcluster","nodes":{"nodeitentifier":{"name":"elastic.server","transport_address":"10.100.2.128:9300","host":"10.100.2.128","ip":"10.100.2.128","version":"7.16.2","build_flavor":"default","build_type":"rpm","build_hash":"2b937c44140b6559905130a8650c64dbd0879cfb","roles":["data","ingest","master"],"attributes":{"xpack.installed":"true","transform.node":"false"}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this configuration was done in both /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf and /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d/inputs.elastic.conf, and that was causing this issue.